# Where can I change the settings of the Xdebug?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, remote-debugging

`phpinfo()` shows the path to the configuration: `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`

But the file contains only a string: `zend_extension=xdebug.so`

The file `usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so` looks like this:

[image]

In php.ini, there are no lines containing "xdeb" or "remote_connect"

UP: What I need? The `phpinfo()` shows that the `xdebug.remote_connect_back` setting is off. I need to turn it on.

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: @AyyappanSekar The `phpinfo()` shows that the `xdebug.remote_connect_back` setting is off. I need to turn it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fill your /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini with something like :

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.max_nesting_level=10000
;...
```

And restart apache. All settings from xdebug are available [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings)